# Removing a specific "Reserved Term" in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need the ability to use the `tag` parameter in WordPress and pass it around page to page. However when I use it, WordPress throws a 404 error due to WordPress's "Reserved Terms".

I need the `tag` param as it's responsible for collecting data such as user device and other important info separated by `-`. I cannot use anything else as there is an existing API which parses the tag param.

Example been: `http://siteurl.test/?tag=tag1-tag2-tag3`

Is there a way to fully remove a specific WordPress "Reserved Terms" seen [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)

I have tried unload the tag taxonomy as it follows a similar structure with the below code, but still causes the 404.

```
function unregister_tags() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'post');
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type('tag', 'post');
}
add_action('init', 'unregister_tags');
```

I have been digging but cannot seem to find anyway to do this. I also cannot use anything like `unset($_GET['tag]);` on a `init` action hook as I pass the data through all pages.

Cheers to anyone who can take the time to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone facing this issue there is a solution. Isn't the cleanest, but it works.

In a nut shell you intercept each query and force ignore any params you set in the below function.

```
add_filter( 'request', 'alter_query_params' );
function alter_query_params( $request ) {
    $param_query = new WP_Query();
    $param_query->parse_query( $request );    
    unset($request['tag']);
    return $request;
}
```